# From where is data sent in Google Tag Manager scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am sending data layer variables from a script configured in Google Tag Manager.

When the trigger fires, the JavaScript gets the data layer variables and other DOM inputs, includes then in a json and sends everything to an external web service that captures the data.

The endpoint (https) works OK when being called from Postman, but not from Chrome (Self-signed SSL certificate not trusted).

The question is:

In production, the the endpoint will be called from the users' browser, or from Google Tag Manager? Because every browser has different security restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Tag Manager compiles all your published settings and custom scripts into a Javascript file, which gets loaded with your page, by the client's browser. The file can be accessed at https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX, where the id is your container ID. This is the same file, that is loaded and executed by the browser. As a result, its content, and any generated call to third party resources are executed by the users' browser, and not by Google Tag Manager, as a service.